# Can I integrate my current PHP scripts into wordpress?

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress

My site has php scripts, but I want to start using wordpress and get a new web host. Long story, don't ask! lol.

Question is, will my current php scripts, which were all time consuming tasks to write, work with wordpress? The scripts access mysql database and display information. That's the just of my website. I would hate to have to re-code everything using WP!

Thanks,
Dav

Comment: Probably not without a bunch of modifications.

Comment: If you want to just plop your code into wordpress and hope it works then you're probably overlooking the purpose of wordpress. A little or a lot of work should always be expected if migrating to a new platform.

Comment: No, it wont be as smooth as I'm sensing you're thinking it will

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Also, Mike B, sorry I'm new to this site so I will start doing that. Thanks again.

Comment: Why do you want to move to Wordpress?  And how do you hope to integrate your current PHP with Wordpress?  You mention your scripts "access mysql database and display information" - arguably, that's exactly what Wordpress does, so it's really hard to answer your question unless you ask more specifics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "yes" and "no".  You may be able to utilize some of what you have done, however be prepared to have to modify you code to make it work in the context of Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the functions.php in the WP template's files.